# Goldbach function and primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I try to check the viability about a conjecture (Goldbach function and primes).

---

$\phi$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $G$ is the goldbach function.
$n$ is a number such that $n = 20000...0$
We have $p=\phi(1+$G$(n))+1$ where $p$ is always a prime number.

My question is: is this conjecture always true?
I failed to test the conjecture because $G$ is too big when I check on wolframalpha.
I have tested the conjecture until $n=20000000$

For example with $n=20000000$ I found $p=45361$ which is prime.
Thanks.

Comment: Why insist on having $n=1999\ldots 9$, and then only use $n+1$? Isn't it easier to just use $n=2000\ldots0$ and talk about $G(n)$ instead? That being said, I strongly suspect that this is entirely a coincidence. There are too many "+1"s all over the place, and those tend to destroy anything that has to do with prime decomposition.

Comment: Ok, I have just edited. In fact it is easier. Now I would like to find a counterexample.

Comment: Download the free and easy to use PARI/GP

Comment: Is there a connection between this equation and the Goldbach-conjecture ? Something like if the Goldbach conjecture is true , this equation has always a solution ? If so, please demonstrate this implication.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Peter. With PARI/GP I have calculated for $n=2000000000$ and I obtain the prime number 2367361.

Comment: I found a counterexample with $n=200000000$, we have 990253 with is not prime.

Comment: So, is there a link between this result (the counterexample) and the Goldbach conjecture?